# Existence of integer solutions to $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2$ for specified $d$

Tags: diophantine-equations, cubics

Previous questions contained cubes instead of squares, that was my mistake, sorry.

How to tell if $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2$ has any integer, non-zero solutions for specified positive integer $d$? Is there any criterium or algorithm for this?

EDIT: To clarify, $a, b, c$ are non-zero integers and $d$ is specified and it is a positive integer.

Comment: Please clarify if you are looking specifically for solutions in which $a,b,c$ are also positive integers, or if $a,b,c$ could be zero or negative as well.  (*a trivial solution would be when $a=d$ and $b=c=0$, but this is rather uninteresting.  a much less trivial solution is posted below, but will cause at least one of the terms to be negative or zero*)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730327/if-n-a2-b2-c2-for-positive-integers-a-b-c-show-that-there-exi/1730343#1730343

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) As regards the original post: existence of integer solutions to
$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = d^3$ for a given $d$.

Note that the following identity holds:
$$(9t^4)^3+(1-9t^3)^3 +(3t-9t^4)^3=1.$$
Therefore, given a positive integer $d$ there is always an integer solution,
$$(9dt^4)^3+(d(1-9t^3))^3+(d(3t-9t^4))^3 = d^3.$$

For more details, take a look at this page (with references): https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/integers-equal-to-the-sum-of-three-cubes/

2) As regards the new post: existence of integer solutions to
 $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2$ for a given $d$.

Note that by a [theorem of Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem), if we allow $a,b,c$ to be zero, then
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2=N$$
iff $N$ is NOT of the form $4^n(8m+7)$.

For numbers that are the sum of three non zero squares see the OEIS sequence [A000408](https://oeis.org/A000408).

In the list we find the squares 9, 36,49, 81 (but not 4,25,64,100).
Since
$$t^2+(t+1)^2+(t(t+1))^2=(t^2+t+1)^2$$
it follows that if $d$ has a divisor of the form $t^2+t+1$ with $t\geq 1$ (like 3, 7, 13,  31, 43) then there is a solution.

According to this [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90914/sums-of-three-non-zero-squares),  there is a finite set $T$ such that any positive integer is a sum of three *non-zero* squares unless $n$ is of the form $4^n(8m+7)$ or of the form $4^am$ where $m\in T$.
It seems that
$$T=\{1,2,5,10,13,25,37,58,85,130\}$$
therefore $a^2 + b^2 + c^2=d^2$ has a solution iff $d\not= 2^n$ or $d\not= 2^n\cdot 5$.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I am very, very sorry. I meant this equations but not with cubes but with squares. I was writing it in the morning and didn't see an error.

Comment: @user4201961 See my edited answer.

Comment: What if I'd want $a, b, c$ to be non-zero?

Comment: @user4201961 See the end of my edited answer.

Comment: @user4201961 I gave a sufficient condition. See the link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @user4201961 It seems that your equation is solvable iff $d\not= 2^n$ or $d\not= 2^n\cdot 5$.